# How to start JavaScript project using WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, ide, development-environment, webstorm

Im new to JavaScript and am ready to start developing my first application.

I have downloaded WebStorm as my IDE and I am confused on how to set things up so I can start coding.  Specifically, can someone walk me through how to begin a project and what steps I must take to be able to code and 'see' a simple "Hello World!" application using webstorm? That would definitely get me going.

Comment: if you can't find the docs on how to get started ....Wow!

Comment: If Webstorm is too advanced for you, consider starting with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: The best resource I have found to answer this question is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTAWd6hxVtI) video by Paul Baumgarten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the [Webstorm quickstart](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/quickstart/) page? It goes over several of the points that you've requested; specifically: Start a Project from Scratch, View Your Changes Instantly, Run and Debug Your Application, among other very helpful topics.

Comment: Thats why this question should be closed.

Comment: The resource linked goes over how to create an empty project and how to create a new file.  This is as close as it gets to a Hello World.  The page is rather a summary of features with links to further explain these features.